# How to replace specific character in HTML String in Swift?

Tags: html, swift, string, replace

I have HTML, parse into String in Swift. HTML comes from server.I have

webkit-playsinline=""

inside String.

I need to replace this

```
"webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline"
```

I made two Strings, for replacement

```
let string1 = "webkit-playsinline=\"\""
let string2 = "webkit-playsinline=\"webkit-playsinline\""
```

But, I am unable to to do Replace as no such method exists.

In short, How can I alter HTML/String in Swift.

Thanks.

Comment: Try like `let newString = htmlString.replacingOccurrences(of: string1, with: string2)`

Comment: can you please show the HTML string here.

Comment: replacingOccurrences is not available in String class.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
let string1 = "webkit-playsinline=\"\""
let string2 = string1.replacingOccurrences(of: "webkit-playsinline=\"\"", with: "webkit-playsinline=\"webkit-playsinline\"")
```

Comment: replacingOccurrences is not part of String class. no such method now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let string1 = "webkit-playsinline=\"\""
 let string2 = "webkit-playsinline=\"webkit-playsinline\""

 yourHTML = (yourHTML as NSString).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(string1, withString: string2)
```

Happy Coding!